# Splitting 4k-monitor into smaller grids

Tags: compiz

is it possible to arrange more window-grids (than 4) on a monitor? Like 4² grids? Running Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity on a 4k-display. Compiz doesn't currently support it i guess. Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [this](http://projects.nickbp.com/gridmgr/) may do what you want. I haven't tested it but it looks interesting. It doesn't appear to be limited in terms of quadrants.